# Annotation over Many to Many field

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I have the following models for a cycling event:

```
class Leg(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(default=now)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Cyclist(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    legs = models.ManyToManyField( Leg, related_name='cyclist')
```

I know I can for each cyclist get a list of the legs that they have chosen - or get for each leg I can get a list of the cyctlists which have chosen that leg.

My problem is this : Given a particular Cyclist, I want to be a able to create a queryset for all legs with a boolean against each leg showing whether this particular cyclist has chosen that leg :

I have this so far :

```
legs = models.Leg.objects.all().order_by('date').annotate( on_leg ???? magic???? )
```

I know given a specific Cyclist instance `cyclist` I can test against a specifc Leg instance `leg` :

```
boolean = leg.cyclists.filter(id=cyclist.id).exists()
```

But I can't get my head around to do something similar on an annotation against a queryset on legs

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with [.extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#extra)

```
legs = Leg.objects.all().order_by('date').extra(
    select={'cyclist_exists': "EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM `myapp_cyclist_legs` \
        WHERE `myapp_cyclist_legs`.`leg_id` = `myapp_leg`.id \
          AND `myapp_cyclist_legs`.`cyclist_id` = %s)" % cyclist.id}
)

#now you can do:
for l in legs:
    print l.cyclist_exists
```

**EDIT:**

Another solution would be to take the whole `Cyclist` object instead of just marking boolean True/False.

```
Leg.objects.all().order_by('date').prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('cyclist', 
        queryset=Cyclist.objects.filter(id=cyclist.id), 
        to_attr='related_cyclist')
)

#this way every leg will have a attr `related_cyclist` 
#which will be whether an empty list or a list with one element - your cyclist object.

for l in legs:
    print l.related_cyclist
```

Comment: oh yucky - is there not a non-SQL way to do this - considering is must be relatively common thing to do.

Comment: If you move this  raw-SQL into a queryset method it will be fine. However take a look in the [new staffs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.8/#query-expressions-conditional-expressions-and-database-functions) coming from Django 1.8, we are still on 1.7 so I haven't go deep into them, but there is probably a way to do it getting a sum for each where cyclist_id=your_id. It will be less performant, but a non-SQL solution.